# Mysql count occurrence by group

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Hi i have following table on mysql DB.

```
╔═══════════╦═════════╦════════╦════════════════╗
║ REVIEW_ID ║ USER_ID ║ STATUS ║   DATE_ADDED   ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬════════╬════════════════╣
║       218 ║       2 ║ cool   ║ 20130121134811 ║
║       218 ║       2 ║ cool   ║ 20130121134812 ║
║       218 ║       2 ║ lame   ║ 20130121134813 ║
║       218 ║       2 ║ funny  ║ 20130121134814 ║
║       218 ║       2 ║ funny  ║ 20130121134815 ║
║       218 ║       2 ║ funny  ║ 20130121134816 ║
║       218 ║       2 ║ lame   ║ 20130121134817 ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╩════════╩════════════════╝
```

how can i get a result where when i do query based on `user_id` i need to get result of total status for each type:

```
╔════════╦════════════╗
║ STATUS ║ TOTALCOUNT ║
╠════════╬════════════╣
║ cool   ║          2 ║
║ funny  ║          3 ║
║ lame   ║          2 ║
╚════════╩════════════╝
```

Thanks

Comment: If you google "Mysql count by group" the first hit gives you a very simple solution: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-count-with-group-by.php

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `COUNT()` which is an aggregate function, and group them according to their `status`

```
SELECT  status, COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY status
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f487/2)

OTHER(s)

- [MySQL GROUP BY with some Aggregate Functions List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT status, count(*)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY status
```

Comment: +1 @fthiella otherwise nobody will vote our correct answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT status, count(*)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY status
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  STATUS, COUNT(*) AS TOTALCOUNT
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY STATUS
HAVING   USER_ID = user_id you need
```